# Implementing Input/Output redirection in a Delphi  console application

Tags: delphi, console, redirect

I have a Delphi 7 (not 2007) application (lets call it App1.exe) that
the IDE thinks is a GUI application but in the DPR, a compiler
directive that makes it in to a console application. Example:

```
{$IFDE MAKE_CONSOLE}
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF MAKE_CONSOLE}
```

During the build process, MAKE_CONSOLE might be defined.

The problem I am having is that we have another console application
(say, App2.exe) that runs App1.exe using the WinAPI CreateProcess. When
is occurs, the output from App1.exe is nowhere to be seen :-( When
App1.exe is ran straight from Commandline (cmd.exe), the output is
shown in the Commandline window.

What I am guessing is that I need to redirect output from App1.exe in
the CreateProcess, using the STARTUPINFO structure. I am not sure what
I am meant to be doing here.

Other info:
* 'dwCreationFlags' that are being used are: CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP +
NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS + DEBUG_PROCESS (yes, App2 debugs App1)

- 'bInheritHandles' is false (does this need to be changed?).
- Both 'lpProcessAttributes' and 'lpThreadAttributes' are nil, as are
  'lpEnvironment' and 'lpCurrentDirectory'.

Have I missed any information that is required to help me out?

Any pointers would be great!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note there's no such thing as a "GUI console" application. It's either one or the other. Since you've set the APPTYPE CONSOLE setting, your program is a console program. What the IDE shows in the project options is irrelevant; it's trumped by the code.

Comment: It seems that App1.exe had three build methods: Gui, Text output and XML file output and I was testing while it was built to produce a XML file output (thus, no output to the console).

Thanks for everyone's suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use for calling command-line programs from Deplhi 7.

It can redirect to the current console (of the main calling exe), if you put the "Visibility" parameter to 0, instead of "SW_SHOWNORMAL".

```
function WinExecAndWait(const FileName: String; Visibility: integer): cardinal;
var StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
    ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
    Options: cardinal;
begin
  FillChar(StartupInfo,Sizeof(StartupInfo),0);
  StartupInfo.cb := Sizeof(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := Visibility;
  if Visibility=0 then begin
    Flush(Output);
    Options := NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
  end else
    Options := CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
  if not CreateProcess(nil,
     pointer(FileName),             { pointer to command line string }
     nil,                           { pointer to process security attributes }
     nil,                           { pointer to thread security attributes }
     false,                         { handle inheritance flag }
     Options,                       { creation flags }
     nil,                           { pointer to new environment block }
     nil,                           { pointer to current directory name }
     StartupInfo,                   { pointer to STARTUPINFO }
     ProcessInfo) then              { pointer to PROCESS_INF }
    Result := cardinal(-1) else begin
    WaitforSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess,Result);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have DETACHED_PROCESS in the process creation flags? Inheriting the parent console should be the default.

Comment: No. The only flags specified are CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS + DEBUG_PROCESS.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article discusses how App2 can redirect App1's output:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ConsoleApp by Martin Lafferty works beautifully for redirecting the output of console programs. You get an event handler that's called for every line of console output.

I can't find the official home for the code, but here's Embarcadero's page:

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/14692